# how to set difference between reply and bounce email

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

im building system, that tracks bounce emails and also when user reply back with message, then other user can read the message of this user.

so far i have read from all the questions / answers, that bounce email can be sent to return-path or also to reply-to path.

how can i tackle this issue? should i scan and see if its bounce email, if its not, then consider it as message email or there is some other way around it?

checking for bounce email and then parsing for message, its just extra overhead, when system is getting lots and lots of emails from bounce or as messages.

Comment: There is no fool-proof way to determine if a message is a bounce, or a reply.  You can write code that makes guesses based on how it came in, and the message contents, but that's it.

Comment: Emails are also rejected when the target server is too busy, when there are a several consecutive emails from the same smtp server, etc. There many reasons why they are rejected. In my experience, the only way to have an idea is by looking the body for determinate message patterns, along with rejection statistics. Check PHPMailer-BMH, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounce should be sent back to address given in `From` while for replies you can provide alternate address in `Reply-To` header. So if you set two different addresses there (ie. `From: bounce@...` and `Reply-To: reply@....`, and process mails arriving

Comment: @Webnetmobilecom some client application might just avoid reply-to and reply back to from address. no? and if its the case, then that would not deliver the message.

Comment: Perhaps, there's lot of bad code in the world, but most will follow these standards. I'd go that way I described at first (as it shall be trivial to implement and deploy), run for some time and monitor if your concerns do apply and how many times it happened